# Mostrar 2 separados por coma de un campo MYSQL

Tags: php, mysqli

```html
 <h3>Complete los datos solicitados</h3>
 <form action="creacion_curso_bd.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" target="_self" id="form1">
  <div class="row form-group">
   <!-- nombre curso -->
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" name="nombre_curso" id="nombre_curso" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre del curso">
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <!-- fin nombre curso -->
  <input type="hidden" id="dir" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ip_usuario; ?>"> <!-- Podría ser <?=$ip?>, como fomra abreviada -->

  <!-- Fecha del curso -->         
  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <input class="form-control required" type="date" name="fecha_curso" id="fecha_curso" placeholder="Fecha de realización">
    <div class="button-group">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary; color: #1f27ba" id="plus5_2">Añadir mas fechas</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" id="minus5_2">Remover fechas</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!--  fin Fecha del curso -->

  <!-- horario del curso -->
  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="time" name="horario_curso" id="horario_curso" class="form-control" placeholder="Horario del curso">
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- fin horario del curso -->

  <!-- Tipo de jornada -->
  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <select name="tipo_jornada" id="tipo_jornada" class="form-control" style="height: 50px" >
     <option value=''>Jornada</option>
     <option value='Diurno'>Diurno</option>
     <option value='Vespertino'>Vespertino</option>
     <option value='Completa'>Completa</option>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- fin Tipo de jornada -->

  <!-- cantidad de horas -->
  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" name="numero_horas" id="numero_horas" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad de horas" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);" >
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- fin cantidad de horas -->

  <!-- codigo SIGPER -->
  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" name="sigper" id="sigper" class="form-control" placeholder="Codigo SIGPER">
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- fin codigo SIGPER -->

  <!-- cantidad de vacantes -->
  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" name="vacantes" id="vacantes" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad de vacantes" onkeypress="return valideKey(event);" >
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- fin cantidad de vacantes -->
  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="text" name="ubicacion" id="ubicacion" class="form-control" placeholder="Ubicación del curso">
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <textarea name="descripcion"  id="descripcion" cols="30" rows="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción del curso"></textarea>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- ambito -->
  <div class="row form-group">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <select name="ambito" id="ambito" class="form-control" style="height: 50px" >
     <option value=''>Elija un ambito</option>
     <?php
     $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM ambito");
     while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      echo '<option value="'.$valores[id_ambito].'">'.$valores[ambito].'</option>';
     }
     ?>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- fin ambito -->

  <!-- relatores -->
  <div class="row form-group" id="dynamic_form">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <select name="p_name" id="p_name" class="form-control" style="height: 50px" >
     <option value=''>Elija un relator</option>
     <?php
     $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT id_relator, nombre_relator FROM relatores");
     while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
      echo '<option value="'.$valores['id_relator'].'">'.$valores['nombre_relator'].'</option>';
     }
     ?>
    </select>
    <div class="button-group">
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary; color: #1f27ba" id="plus5">Añadir mas relatores</a>
     <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" id="minus5">Remover Relator</a>
    </div>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
      var dynamic_form =  $("#dynamic_form").dynamicForm("#dynamic_form","#plus5", "#minus5", {
       limit:10,
       formPrefix : "dynamic_form",
       normalizeFullForm : false
      });

      dynamic_form.inject([{p_name: 'Hemant',quantity: '123',remarks: 'testing remark'},{p_name: 'Harshal',quantity: '123',remarks: 'testing remark'}]);

      $("#dynamic_form #minus5").on('click', function(){
       var initDynamicId = $(this).closest('#dynamic_form').parent().find("[id^='dynamic_form']").length;
       if (initDynamicId === 2) {
        $(this).closest('#dynamic_form').next().find('#minus5').hide();
       }
       $(this).closest('#dynamic_form').remove();
      });

      $('form').on('submit', function(event){
       var values = {};
       $.each($('form').serializeArray(), function(i, field) {
        values[field.name] = field.value;
       });
       console.log(values) 
       event.preventDefault();
      })
     });
    </script>
    <!-- fin relatores -->
   </div> </div>      
   <br>
   <div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <a href="relatores_embed.php?keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=280&amp;width=680" class="thickbox">    <h3>Si quiere agregar otro relator al listado, haga click aquí</h3>  </a>
     <input type="submit" name="enviar" onclick="valida_envia()" value="Enviar inscripción" class="btn btn-primary" id="enviar">
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
```

En este formulario tengo un `select` de "Relatores" (tutores), con un `script` en `JS` que añade mas `select`, en caso de que el curso tenga mas de 1 relator, el `select` tienen como `option_value` el `id` del relator, y al guardar el formulario, tomo el `array` de los `select` generados y los guardo en una base de datos `mysql`, en este `PHP`:

```html
  $nombre_curso=$_POST["nombre_curso"];
  $horario_curso=$_POST["horario_curso"];
  $tipo_jornada=$_POST["tipo_jornada"];
  $codigo_sigper=$_POST["sigper"];
  $vacantes=$_POST["vacantes"];
  $ubicacion=$_POST["ubicacion"];
  $descripcion=$_POST["descripcion"];
  $id_ambito=$_POST["ambito"];
  $horas_curso=$_POST["numero_horas"];
  $fecha_curso=$_POST["fecha_curso"];

  //recibes el valor del formulario 
  $arr_relatores= (isset($_POST["dynamic_form"]))?$_POST["dynamic_form"]["dynamic_form"]:null;
  //creas un array simple
  $arr_rel = array();
  foreach ($arr_relatores as $key_rel => $row_rel) $arr_rel[$key_rel] = $row_rel['p_name'];
  //parseas el array para imprimirlo como texto.
  $p_name = implode(', ', $arr_rel);


  if (empty($_POST["nombre_curso"]) or empty($_POST["vacantes"]) or empty($_POST["ubicacion"]) ) {
  echo"<Script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
   alert('!Datos faltantes, favor de verificar los campos requeridos!')
   window.location.href='creacion_curso.php';
  </Script>";

 }else{


 $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
 $curso_nom = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `nombre_curso` FROM `cursos` WHERE `nombre_curso` = '$nombre_curso'"); 
 echo $curso_nom;


 if ($curso_nom==null){

 $sql = ("INSERT INTO `capacitaciones`.`cursos` (`nombre_curso`, `fechas_curso`, `horario_curso`, `tipo_jornada`, `horas_curso`, `id_ambito`, `codigo_sigper`, `vacantes`, `ubicacion`, `descripcion`, `id_relator`, `disponible`) VALUES ('$nombre_curso', '$fecha_curso', '$horario_curso', '$tipo_jornada', '$horas_curso', '$id_ambito', '$codigo_sigper', '$vacantes', '$ubicacion', '$descripcion', '$p_name', 'si')"); //Se insertan los datos a la base de datos y el usuario ya fue registrado con exito.  


 if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)) { 
  scriptAlertGo('!El curso fue inscrito correctamente!','../bienvenido.php');
 }else{
  scriptAlert('!Ha ocurrido un problema en la inscripción, por favor intente nuevamente!','creacion_curso.php');
 }    
 }else{
  scriptAlertGo('El nombre del curso ya esta registrado en la base de datos','../bienvenido.php');
  }
 }
```

En parte de ese código, logro tomar los `ID` de relatores y quedan guardados en la base de datos, estos quedan en el campo "id_relatores" de mi tabla "cursos", y en ella se guardan así: 1, 3, 6

El detalle esta en que, en otro `PHP`, muestro los datos del curso realizado, entre ellos el o los relatores, y en ese campo tengo el siguiente `select`:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!-- relatores del curso -->
<div class="row form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="fname" style="margin-left: 15px;">Relatores del curso: </label> 
        <?php
        $id_relator=$_POST["id_relator"];
        $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'capacitaciones');
        $con->set_charset("utf8"); 
        $result = mysqli_query($conex, "SELECT nombre_relator FROM relatores where id_relator='$id_relator'");
        if($result)
        {
            while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_object($result))
            {  
                echo "<input type='hidden' id='id_relator' name='id_relator' value='$id_relator'>"; 
                echo $registro->nombre_relator.PHP_EOL;  
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>    
<!-- fin relatores del curso -->
```

Comment: ¿Has pensado en normalizar la tabla a 1NF? cada relator deberia ser un registro no un campo con varios relatores.

Comment: Que cada relator sea un campo único?  En un principio si, lo que pasa es que me solicitaron añadir mas relatores, ya que un curso puede tener mas de 1 relator, y las 2 tablas que uso son 

Relatores: con campos id_relator y nombre_relator

Cursos: donde esta tb el campo id_relator

Comment: Un campo unico NO, un registro (fila), de lo que expones se desprende una relacion N:M, por lo que seria conveniente tener una tabla intermedia con los relatores relacionados con los cursos, donde se almacena el id_curso y el id_relator. De esta forma puedes desglosar una realacion N:M en dos relaciones 1:N.

Comment: Ahora te entiendo, le voy a dar una vuelta en desarrollo y ver que se da

Comment: puede ser mas sencillo de lo que piensas revisa las funciones implode y explode de php

Comment: @RobinsonReyes Si, es verdad que se podría conseguir una solución con explode para este caso concreto, pero esto conllevaría realizar multiples consultas para extraer los datos, asi como realizar consultas mas costasas y complejas en las operaciones que puedan derivarse de los datos. Normalizar los datos a 3NF es lo mas recomendable y ademas evitara dolores de cabeza en el futuro.

Comment: Gracias Xerif, pero tengo el problema de que traigo el array del campo "fecha de cursos", me suma los dos con una coma y nose como separar ese array para poder guardarlos en una tabla